PlatformException(io_exception, null, null, null) Error When Reading and Writing NFC Data in Flutter
I'm working on a Flutter application that involves both reading and writing NFC tags using the nfc_manager package. However, I encounter a PlatformException(io_exception, null, null, null) error when performing these operations.
The app doesn't read anything from the tag, and it doesn't allow to write into it using the form (i'm supposed to save the info as Bytes)
Implementation of my NfcService class:
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/platform_tags.dart';

class NfcService {
  /// Checks if NFC is available on the device
  Future<bool> isNfcAvailable() async {
    try {
      return await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error checking NFC availability: $e');
      return false;
    }
  }

  /// Starts an NFC session and listens for NFC tags
  Future<NfcTag?> startNfcSession() async {
    Completer<NfcTag?> completer = Completer();

    try {
      NfcManager.instance.startSession(
        onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
          completer.complete(tag);
          NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error starting NFC session: $e');
      completer.completeError(e);
    }

    return completer.future;
  }

  /// Writes form data to an NFC tag
  Future<void> writeFormData(
    NfcTag tag, {
    required String productName,
    required String productDescription,
  }) async {
    try {
      if (tag.data.containsKey('mifareultralight')) {
        var mifareUltralight = MifareUltralight.from(tag);

        if (mifareUltralight != null) {
          // Prepare data
          String dataToWrite = '$productName\n$productDescription';
          List<int> data = dataToWrite.codeUnits; // Convert string to bytes

          // MifareUltralight write requires the page number and data to be written
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
            final pageData = Uint8List(4)
              ..setAll(0,
                  data.sublist(i, i + 4 > data.length ? data.length : i + 4));

            // Write data to page
            await mifareUltralight.transceive(
              data: Uint8List.fromList(
                  [0xA2, i ~/ 4, ...pageData]), // 0xA2 is the WRITE command
            );
          }

          debugPrint('Data written successfully');
        } else {
          debugPrint('MifareUltralight instance is null');
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint('Unsupported card type');
      }
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      debugPrint('Failed to write to NFC tag: $e');
      debugPrint('Stacktrace: $stacktrace');
      throw Exception('Failed to write to NFC tag: $e');
    }
  }

  /// Reads data from an NFC tag
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> readTagData() async {
    try {
      Completer<Map<String, dynamic>> completer = Completer();
      NfcTag? tag;

      NfcManager.instance.startSession(
        onDiscovered: (NfcTag discoveredTag) async {
          tag = discoveredTag;
          NfcManager.instance.stopSession();

          try {
            final data = await _readTag(tag);
            completer.complete(data);
          } catch (e) {
            completer.completeError(e);
          }
        },
      );

      return completer.future;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error reading NFC tag data: $e');
      return {'tagType': 'Unknown', 'data': 'Error: $e'};
    }
  }

  /// Helper method to read data from an NFC tag
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _readTag(NfcTag? tag) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> tagData = {};

      if (tag == null) {
        throw Exception('No tag detected');
      }

      if (tag.data.containsKey('mifareultralight')) {
        var mifareUltralight = MifareUltralight.from(tag);

        if (mifareUltralight != null) {
          // Read data from multiple pages
          List<int> allData = [];
          for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
            final response = await mifareUltralight.transceive(
              data: Uint8List.fromList([0x30, i]), // 0x30 is the READ command
            );
            allData.addAll(response.sublist(0, 4)); // Each page is 4 bytes
          }

          tagData['data'] = String.fromCharCodes(allData).trim();
        } else {
          tagData['data'] = 'Unsupported tag type';
        }
      } else {
        tagData['data'] = 'Unsupported tag type';
      }

      return tagData;
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      debugPrint('Error reading tag data: $e');
      debugPrint('Stacktrace: $stacktrace');
      return {'data': 'Error: $e'};
    }
  }
}


Formulaire_page.dart :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:soremar_inventory/services/nfc_service.dart';
import 'package:soremar_inventory/widgets/my_text_field.dart';

class FormulairePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String path = '/formulaire';

  const FormulairePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormulairePage> createState() => _FormulairePageState();
}

class _FormulairePageState extends State<FormulairePage> {
  final _productController = TextEditingController();
  final _productDesController = TextEditingController();
  final NfcService _nfcService = NfcService();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _productController.dispose();
    _productDesController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 48, 161),
        title: const Text("Form"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            MyTextField(
                myController: _productController,
                fieldName: "Product Name",
                myIcon: Icons.account_balance,
                prefixIconColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 48, 161)),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            MyTextField(
                myController: _productDesController,
                fieldName: "Product Description",
                prefixIconColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 48, 161)),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            myBtn(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  OutlinedButton myBtn(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: const Size(200, 50)),
      onPressed: () {
        _submitForm(context);
      },
      child: Text(
        "Submit Form".toUpperCase(),
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submitForm(BuildContext context) async {
    final productName = _productController.text;
    final productDescription = _productDesController.text;

    try {
      // Start NFC session and get the tag
      final tag = await _nfcService.startNfcSession();
      if (tag != null) {
        // Write data to the NFC tag
        await _nfcService.writeFormData(
          tag,
          productName: productName,
          productDescription: productDescription,
        );
        _showSuccessDialog(context);
      } else {
        _showErrorDialog(context, 'No NFC tag detected.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to write NFC tag: $e');
      _showErrorDialog(context, e.toString());
    }
  }

  void _showSuccessDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Success'),
          content: const Text('Data written to NFC tag successfully.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showErrorDialog(BuildContext context, String error) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Error'),
          content: Text('Failed to write NFC tag: $error'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


scan_page.dart :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:soremar_inventory/services/nfc_service.dart';

class ScanTagPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScanTagPage({super.key});

  @override
  ScanTagPageState createState() => ScanTagPageState();
}

class ScanTagPageState extends State<ScanTagPage> {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>>? _scanResult;
  final NfcService _nfcService = NfcService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Controller un produit'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 48, 161),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Background GIF
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/scan.gif', // Ensure the path is correct
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          // Foreground content
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _showScanDialog(context),
              child: const Text('Cliquez ici pour scanner une tag NFC'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showScanDialog(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      _scanResult = _startNfcScan();
    });

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // Prevents closing dialog by tapping outside
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Scan NFC'),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/scan.gif', // Ensure the path is correct
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            const Text(
                'Placez votre téléphone près de l\'étiquette NFC pour scanner.'),
            FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
              future: _scanResult,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final tagData = snapshot.data;
                  final data = tagData?['data'] ?? 'No data';
                  return Text('Data: $data');
                } else {
                  return const Text('No tag detected.');
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close dialog
            },
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _startNfcScan() async {
    try {
      final tag = await _nfcService.startNfcSession();
      if (tag != null) {
        return await _nfcService.readTagData();
      } else {
        return {'data': 'No tag detected.'};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return {'data': 'Error: $e'};
    }
  }
}


Steps taken so far :Added permissions in AndroidManifest.xmlVerified NFC functionality with other apps
